# Trying to close an FTP connection in .NET just hangs

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, proftpd

I'm trying to close my ftp connection to some ftp and it just hangs... forever!

- it only happens against 1 FTP server, so I'm assuming there's something bad setup with that server. Code works fine against other servers.
- only happens when the file I'm uploading is huge (180mb). Connection closes fine when file(s) are small.
- destination FTP server is running **220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server (Debian)**
- For the large file, start time: 15:53:18.701. End time: 16:00:22.179; Roughly 7 mins.
- The 180MB file *is* 100% uploaded .. so it's when I'm trying to close the connection to complete the transfer and then continue in my code.

Here's the code:

```
using (var ftpStream = await ftpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            await inputStream.CopyToAsync(ftpStream);

            _loggingService.Debug("Closing service....");
            ftpStream.Close();
            _loggingService.Debug("Closed..");
        }
```

Yes, I know I don't really need to call `.Close();` because I'm in a `using` statement but I did this to pinpoint to problem.

Comment: What does your method signature look like?

Comment: [Enable logging](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9664650/850848) and show is the log. + How long did you try to wait? + For a simplicity, can you debug this with synchronous streams?

Comment: Are you using FTP over SSL by any chance?

Comment: @Castaglian nope - it's not.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl dude. Dude! awesome suggestion!! So I turned it on and started seeing the `FtpWebRequest` low level traffic .. but nothing stood out. I saw the BeginFtpWebRequest or whatever it was called for the STOR and then nothing really else. Mind you, this is in an Azure Web Job so there was all this frickin webjob-http logging noise/spam I had to fight/try-and-filter out ...

Comment: Can you show us the log anyway? Preferably using the synchronous streams. And a log for a successful transfer for a comparison. + Again, how long did you try to wait?

Comment: I'll try and get a log in the next day or so. it's hard with all the noise from the webjob 'heartbeat home' http calls. I think i waited about 20 - 30 mins. i think? I also have `KeepAlive` = true on. i'll try and post some log data including the initial handshake etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// after finished uploading
ftpWebRequest.Abort();   // <=== MAGIC PART
// before ftpStream.Close()
```

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/385c34c9-de4e-46c9-ad52-00a654c9414f) (and also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908589/7850)).